# How to the contents of an applet into an image?

Tags: java, applet, bufferedimage, graphics2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a Graphics2D to an Image or BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575578/convert-a-graphics2d-to-an-image-or-bufferedimage)

Sorry. This is a very basic question. But I am very new to this platform. I am drawing a line using graphics2d draw function. I want to save this as an image into my system. I googled it out and found out that `BufferedImage` class is useful in doing this and then use imagedraw function.

But I could not figure out how exactly use it in my code. Can any one please help me?

Here is my code.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DrawAndSaveImage extends JApplet {
    public void init() {
        setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    }

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(50,150,150,150 ));

}

public static void main(String s[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("sample image");
    JApplet applet = new DrawAndSaveImage();
    frame.getContentPane().add("Center", applet);
    applet.init();
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.show();
}
}
```

Comment: See also [`ComponentImageCapture`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe/5853992#5853992).

Comment: You're welcome.  Note the 'signed' comment by Nikolay (and my clarification in comment).  While the applet appears in a frame it will not have a `SecurityManager`, but it certainly will when it is embedded in a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `JFrame` and `main` are not supposed to be used in an applet, unless you try to create hybrid application.
2. Don't override `paint()` method
3. Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to create GUI
4. Applet is not allowed to write/read from external files, unless it is signed
5. `ImageIO.write()` can write an image to file

Comment: 1. *"..unless you try to create hybrid application."*  That is another way of showing an applet in a frame.  OTOH I wondered why it was in the example.  2. That could use expanding.  Note that a `JApplet` has no `paintComponent(Graphics)` method. 3. That's good. 4. *"..unless it is signed"* ..or uses the JNLP API services ([demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html)). 5. That's good.  +1

Comment: @AndrewThompson Can I just save the graphics into an image. instead of loading it into applet. Please let me know. Any sample code links. (That would be great.)

Comment: *"instead of loading it into applet."*  The answer is probably yes, but I am a little unclear on why the applet is there at all.  Note that I could achieve this in a command line app. (no GUI).  Here is an [example of painting directly to an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440201/how-to-resize-text-in-java/13440543#13440543).

Answer (score 1):

First, you can create a `BufferedImage` instance like this:

```
    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(600, 800, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Then you can get the `Graphics2d` object from it:

```
    Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
```

Then, you can use the [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) API to save the image.

Comment: That `600, 800` is less than optimal for this use-case.  Instead use the preferred or actual size of the component.

Comment: Right, I used it as an example.